# Animating :after in css

Tags: css

Im trying to figure out why this simple code isn't working.

http://jsfiddle.net/yq1ro6n5/

```
@keyframes testing {
    from: {font-size: 42px;}
    to: {font-size: 64px;}
}
a:after {
    content: "Hello!";
    animation: testing 1s infinite;
}
```

-

```
<a></a>
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `:`  from the keyframe like this

```
@keyframes testing {
from {
    font-size: 42px;
}
to {
    font-size: 64px;
}
}
```

```css
a {
}
@keyframes testing {
    from {
        font-size: 42px;
    }
    to {
        font-size: 64px;
    }
}
a:after {
    content:"Hello!";
    animation: testing 3s infinite;
}
```

```html
<a></a>
```

Comment: How did I miss that, need more coffee I guess. Thanks!

Comment: np :) @Jake Glad i could help